# Javascript call() method

Tags: javascript, call

I understand this code works:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function(){
        console.log(this);
    }).call(links[i]);
}
```

but why does this work:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log.call(this, links[i]);
}
```

isn't *this* supposed to be window object in context of calling every iteration?

Comment: obviously, whatever `this` is in `console.log` is unimportant

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually I think you might be wrong. I remember `console.log` being weird in that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - wasn't long ago that `this` had to be `console` object - but, these days it does not

Comment: "why does this work" — Why shouldn't it? "isn't this supposed to be window object in context of calling every iteration?" — What about the log function's use of `this` means it shouldn't be `window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no different from calling

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i]);
}
```

You are right, in this scope the `this` keyword is bound to the `window` object, if you run the snippet bellow, you can see that I append a new property `SomeUniqueValue` to the window object which becomes accessible inside the scope of the look when using the `call` function.

Now, if you wrap that block inside a function, you can see the the `this` keyword is limited to the scope of the calling block, hence in the last example only the `span` gets logged to the console.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i]);
}

window.SomeUniqueValue = "WAWAWIWA";
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log.call(this, SomeUniqueValue);
}

var someFunction = function() {
  'use strict';
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      console.log.call(this, links[i]);
  }
}

someFunction();
```

```html
<div>This</div>
<div>Works</div>
<div>Fine</div>
<span>Inner Scope</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I guess the part that confuses me is why I can't call it like this:
`console.log.call(links[i], this)`
is it possible to set links[i] as this, or do I lack knowledge on some basic javascript concepts?

Comment: You can't call it that way because the function expects the first parameter to define the context, then the following parameters are the arguments that you Would pass to the Console.Log function, so by calling it like that you would be doing something like console.log(this) where this is bound to the scope of l[i]. The function behaves differently if it only gets one argument, as in your original example. Hope that makes sense!